# Error deserializing import data when run "jss deploy app --includeContent"

Tags: jss

I am using Sitecore 10 with JSS. When I tried to deploy my app to Sitecore I got the below error

> Sitecore has accepted import task JSSImport-atlp-informational-web-1:17:10 PM
> Job started: JSSImport-atlp-informational-web-1:17:10 PM
> Importing atlp-informational-web as sitecore\JssImport
> Import database is master
> Error deserializing import data
> Exception: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException
> Message: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '[0].template', line 3, position 17.
> Source: Newtonsoft.Json
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringValue(ReadType readType)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsString()
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)

I think the error coming from the content as when I used this command `jss deploy app`, the app deployed successfully without the content as below.

[image]

But I cannot find the reason of this error. Any Ideas?

Comment: Indication for you should be this part of error: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value. Make sure indentation of yml files is correct. Try to revert (changed) files one by one to find the one which is causing trouble